# terraform maven coordinates azure artifacts

Tags: azure, maven, coordinates, artifacts, terraform-provider-databricks

I am trying to get Azure Artifacts (maven library install on a Databricks cluster). I am trying to follow the terraform [documentation](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/databrickslabs/databricks/latest/docs/resources/cluster) but I struggle to get right coordinates. Do you know what is the correct URL for the Azure Artifact ?

```
library {
  maven {
    coordinates = "com.amazon.deequ:deequ:1.0.4"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I just learned by reading documentation that currently databricks labs does not provide network authentication, so it will not work in private Azure Artifacts.